# Teach Safari to ignore case if necessary when opening local html file

Tags: safari, safari-extensions, file

I'm using Safari to read the HTML documentation that came with something.  Many of the .html files contain links to others amongst themselves where the case of the URL does not match the name of the file.  For example, somefile.html contains

```
<A HREF="AnotherFile.html">...</A>
```

but the actual file is named anotherfile.html, all lower case.

The easy workaround is to edit the URL in Safari's address bar, fine for just once but gets tedious when I'm hopping around reading massive amounts of brain fodder.  A harder but once-only workaround is to edit the .html files by hand (or clever perl script or whatever), but I don't want to lose the fixes if I upgrade the thing or have to install it on another machine. (And I don't feel like doing such grunt work today.)

Is there a Safari extension or something that can make Safari try a little harder when opening files, to be case insensitive if it doesn't initially find an exact match?   This needs to work only for file: protocol.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behaviour. Have you formatted your drive to be case sensitive?

Comment: Also cannot reproduce this behavior. Do edit the question to provide some more details once you've ruled out a case-sensitive file system on your mac. (which are not default and would cause the failure you describe)

Comment: You mean its normal for Safari to open a file whose name doesn't match the case of the URL it's given?  How do I tell if this mac has a case sensitive file system? Aren't all filesystems case sensitive?

Comment: No, not all filesystems are case-sensitive, and you can actually choose between case-sensitive or no when formatting a drive as HFS+ (the Mac OS X filesystem). The default should be case-sensitive, though.

Answer (score 1):

If you do have your drive formatted as case sensitive, use Disk Utility (Applications->Disk Utility) to create a non-case sensitive disk image. Copy all the files over to said disk image and you should be good to go.

It's a little bit of a pain to mount the disk image when you need to look at the files, but probably far easier than attempting to normalize the upper/lower caseness of every filename & href in the html.